# Need some explanation what is this C# weird syntax

Tags: c#, syntax

I have seen following c# class:

```
public class Bucket: ObservableObject
{
   private ObjectId _oid;
   public ObjectId Oid
   {
      get { return _oid; }
      set
      {
         Set(() => Oid, ref _oid, value);
      }
   }
}
```

I understand `_oid` is a property of class Bucket. But I don't understand this:

```
Set(() => Oid, ref _oid, value);
```

How is it setting this property? Please explain me this syntax? What is it doing?

Comment: From [docs](http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/WP8/html/119ae2f1-46e5-c572-3dff-5492c69bc82c.htm) "Assigns a new value to the property. Then, raises the PropertyChanged event if needed."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ObservableObject` probably wants to notify clients of property changes, so when setting the internal field it also needs the name of the property; this is what `() => Oid` is for. The first parameter to set is probably an `Expression<Func<TResult>>`, which means the compiler does not generate code for the lambda, but rather builds a representation of the code as an abstract syntax tree (AST), which is passed to the `Set` method. This allows the `Set` method to inspect the AST and get the name of the property. If you use newer versions of C#, then `Set` also has an overload allowing you to pass the name of the property rather than the expression. I would use that as it has lower overhead:   `Set(nameof Oid, ref _oid, value);`

The field is being set because you pass it by `ref` (`ref _oid`), so changes to the parameter inside `Set` will be reflected as changes to the field sent as a parameter.

Comment: nice details explanation. Thaks a lot!